# Designing a font definition with multiple variants per glyph

Tags: javascript, json, complexity

My project [penhand](https://github.com/ccprog/penhand) tries to visualize the process of writing with a pen. Part of the project is an engine that converts text entry into a sequence of glyphs that are then rendered as animation into a HTML `<canvas>`. The other part is a file format for fonts and the development of actual fonts.

Writing in a handwritten script has the particularity that the lines forming a glyph should, if possible, connect to the previous and next glyph. Forms of the glyph may differ depending on whether they connect or not. This is a problem quite common to arabic scripts, and some terminology has developed. If a glyph is presented without connections, it is called 'isolate', if connected on both sides 'medial', and 'initial' and 'final' for one-sided connections.

So far, this has proven to be managable. The function tasked with selecting the right variant for a glyph in the sequence is complex, but still readable. But now I am designing a font for this system where I find that these four variants are not enough. The distance between two neighbouring glyphs is constant, but the way the line approaches the cut between them must differ for a smooth look. Let me give you an example:

[image]

The font file is a JSON format where individual glyphs look like this (I am leaving out the meta tables containing information about things like replacements, ligatures and kerning).

```
"e": {
    "medial": {
        "advance": 36,
        "strokes": [ // the geometry of a variant is made up out of multiple strokes
            {
                "d": "...", // geometry
                "pause": "move", // animation instructions
                "late": false
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "final": ...,    // the strokes for these will mostly be identical but for
    "initial": ...,  // minor variations
    "isolate": ...
}
```

I could have added other variants for my new font, but I shy away for two reasons:

- I would have to invent terminology I have not seen anywhere so far.
- Most of the geometry information is just repetition between variants, with at most the first and the last stroke containing a difference.

Instead, I tend to repeating stroke variations *within* the existing variants, marking them with properties of the identifying values `left` and `right` like this:

```
"e": { // the id of a glyph is its character(s)
    "medial": {
        "advance": 36,
        "strokes": [
            {
                "d": "...",
                "atfirst": "right", // marks it as the first stroke having the
                                    // connecting variant "right". Each connecting
                                    // first stroke has one of the two values.
                "pause": "move",
                "late": false
            },
            ...,
            {
                "d": "...",
                "atlast": "left",  // marks it as the last stroke. Each connecting
                                   // last stroke has to exist two times,
                                   // one for each of the two values.
                "late": false
            },
            {
                "d": "...",
                "atlast": "right",
                "late": false
            },
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

You could argue `atfirst` should be a property of the glyph variant, not the stroke, but for now the JSON is compiled out of a customized SVG file, and the parser only checks individual strokes for optional properties.

A class `GlyphChooser` is tasked with converting character sequences to glyph sequences. Among other steps, it has a method `connect`:

```
connect(seq) { // receives a list of glyph ids
    const selection = [];

    seq.forEach((glyph, i) => {
        const select = { glyph, variant: 'isolate', kerning: 0 };

        // retrieve preceding and following glyph
        const last = selection[i - 1];
        // this.#flatFont is a preprocessed variant of the above JSON
        const next = seq[i + 1] && this.#flatFont[seq[i + 1]];

        // check which variants are available. Not all glyphs have all four variants;
        // for example uppercase letters can never connect backwards
        const canBackward = ['initial', 'medial'].includes(last?.variant);
        const canForward = next?.final || next?.medial;

        if (this.glyphs[glyph]) {
            if (canBackward) {
                if (canForward && this.#flatFont[glyph].medial) {
                    select.variant = 'medial'
                } else {
                    select.variant = 'final';
                }
            } else {
                if (canForward && this.#flatFont[glyph].initial) {
                    select.variant = 'initial';
                    // here a selection of the "left" and "right" variant
                    // would have to cut in:
                    select.last = canForward.strokes.find(variant => variant.atfirst).atfirst;
                }

                if (i > 0) {
                    select.kerning = this.#findKerning(last.glyph, glyph);
                }
            }
        } else {
            select.glyph = ' ';
        }
        selection.push(select);
    });

    // get the strokes making up the glyph sequence in the right order
    return this.#order(selection);
}
```

Then, the most fitting place to choose the connecting variant would be inside the `#order` method, although its name then would become misleading. But its task already is to convert the sequence of glyph variants into a sequence of ordered strokes:

```
#order(selection) {
    const instruction = [];
    let position = 0;

    for (const {glyph, variant, kerning, last } of selection) {
        const { strokes, advance } = this.#flatFont[glyph][variant];

        position += kerning;

        // here the selection would take place.
        const usedStrokes = strokes.filter(s => !s.atlast || (s.atlast === last));

        // what follows is about ordering the strokes, code is shortened
        ...
        const regular = {
            strokes: usedStrokes.filter(s => !s.late),
            position
        };
        ...
        // fill the stroke array
        instruction.push(...);

        position += advance;
    }

    return instruction;
}
```

What do you think? Is this the right direction to go forward?